# Forward to a friend mail

Tags: marketing-cloud

Need some help regarding the "Manage Subscription | Unsubscribe" in the newsletter.

Lets take the example,
Suppose 1 users get the newsletter, now this users can view the "Manage Subscription | Unsubscribe" link.

This users will click the "Forward to a Friend" in the newsletter and sent this newsletter 2 users i.e,  UserA and UserB.

Now the thing is that i wanted to hide "Manage Subscription | Unsubscribe" to UserA and UserB.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExactTarget allows for `_MessageContext` to be checked during the send, and creates different renderings for different viewing contexts.

The various contexts are:

- SEND
- PREVIEW
- VAWP
- VIEWSENT
- FTAF
- LANDINGPAGE
- VALIDATION
- LINDRESOLUTION
- SMS
- VOICE
- SOCIAL
- PLATFORM
- SITE

The code you should try is:

```
%%[ if  _MessageContext != "FTAF" then ]%%

%%unsub_center_url%%
%%subscription_center_url%%

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Also if I am directly forwarding the newsletter to my friend.Then Both link "Manage Subscription | Unsubscribe" will work in my friend mail.Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: There is no way to stop the direct forwarding issue.  Please be sure to mark this as answered for the FTAF question.

Comment: Make sure you mark this answered, as it directly answers your question.